# OpenCV Python capture fails if I access a webcame again after releasing it

Tags: python, opencv, stream, webcam

I'm developing a multi-threaded application to capture images from four USB web cameras. For simplicity and early development, I'm using Logitech C920 at 640x480 and 30fps.

I have a simple function that opens a camera and sets some parameters, then releases the camera. Because this is a multithreaded app, four threads each are running this when a button is pressed. It works great.

```
def camParameter(previewName, camID):
    #Set camera object and set parameters
    start_time = time.time()
    cam_test = True
    while cam_test:  
        cam = cv2.VideoCapture(camID)  
        present_time = time.time()
        if present_time - start_time > 2:
            print("Could not open camera ", str(camID))
            break
        if cam.isOpened():
            cam_test=False

    width = 640
    height = 480
    fps = 30
    test_width = cam.get(3)
    test_height = cam.get(4)
    test_fps = cam.get(5)

    if test_width != width:
        cam.set(3,width) 
    if test_height != height:
        cam.set(4,height) 
    if test_fps != fps:
        cam.set(5,fps) 

    print("Parameters set for camera ", str(camID))
    cam.release()
```

However, if I call the function again, or attempt to open the camera to stream, I get the following error:

> VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L2: Pixel format of incoming image is unsupported by OpenCV
>   Unable to stop the stream: Device or resource busy

I can open the camera with GUVCviewer, or unplug/replug the camera to get access back.

Any ideas why a second access of the camera would cause this issue, or how to fix it?

I have verified the camera is in-fact released. I can access the camera

Comment: I've tried it and it works. Could you try updating opencv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recompiled openCV with GStreamer - it's much more multithread friendly.